# how to read every 5 digits in a file without invisible characters in c in linux?

Tags: c, linux, file

I want to read every 5 characters but when I print the output I get less than 5 characters since there are invisible characters in the source file. How can I skip them?

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(buf);i++){
// perform some operation 
}
printf("%s",buf);
```

Comment: Is it a text file? Why do you have invisible characters in a text file?

Comment: Loop through the characters in `buf` and use `isgraph()` to tell if it's a printing character, and only print those.

Comment: Show us a hex dump of some of the sample input.  Is it UTF-16 by any chance, so the invisible characters are null bytes?  (`xxd -g 1 input_file | sed 3q` would probably generate appropriate output).  If the input is UTF-16, you'll have to work hard.  If the format is something else, it may be easier.  You should show the output you expect for the hex dump input you show.

Comment: yes. The source was given for the assignment. The source file has numbers and invisible character .. I checked with isdigit().

Comment: You have the file; we don't.  We can't help you unless you show us what you've got (and what you expect to see from what you've got).  It sounds like a problematic format, but we can't tell how problematic because we can't see it.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: I can't do anything to the source.txt.

Comment: Yes you can.  You can read it.  You can look at it with tools.  Without information about what is really in the file — the byte sequence — there is nothing we can do to help you.  You shouldn't modify the file; that's OK.  We want to help you read the file as given.  If you hack it, it won't help.  The `xxd` and `sed` command reads the file and presents the output so we can interpret it.  Without that information, there's nothing anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful function [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) defined in `ctype.h` that checks exactly what you're asking - if the char is a space.

There are several additional interesting functions for characters classification defined there as well ([more information](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace)):

```
int isalnum(int c);
int isalpha(int c);
int iscntrl(int c);
int isdigit(int c);
int isgraph(int c);
int islower(int c);
int isprint(int c);
int ispunct(int c);
int isspace(int c);
int isupper(int c);
int isxdigit(int c);
int isascii(int c);
int isblank(int c);
```

In fact there are 3 families of functions to classify characters, for [byte strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), for [wide strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide) and for [multi-byte strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte)

For your example to avoid any kind of spaces using `en_US.UTF-8` locale:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char * BUF = " a\vb\nc d\tefghijk";
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");

    for (int i = 0, c = 5; i < strlen(BUF) && c > 0;++i){
        unsigned char chr = BUF[i];
        if (isspace(chr))
                continue;
        printf("%c", chr);
        c--;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Don't forget that these functions depends on the encoding. Same characters may have different classifications for different encodings.